# uploaded images not going to /uploads folder

Tags: uploads

having a huge problem with a site.  i updated the theme to use post thumbnails (that's how old it is) and then when trying to upload an image to use as featured thumbnail: the images process/crunch but then the URLs result in 404s.

[image]

there isn't anything abnormal in the site's .htaccess.  there actually wasn't a wp-content/uploads directory so i made one and the chmod permissions are 0755, so that shouldn't be the issue.  i reset the media settings folder to be the default but no images are ending up in that folder.

edit: changing the uploads folder to 0777 permissions seems to resolve this.  is it safe to leave the permissions this way?

Comment: Definitely not on the 777.

Comment: that's what i thought, but the images don't upload without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember it right, this happened to me once. I deleted my `/uploads` directory (to delete all the images) and went back to posting thinking that WordPress will automatically create an `/uploads` directory and any necessary sub-directories for me.

And yes, that's how it works. But here's the catch -- WordPress doesn't set proper permissions for the `/uploads` directory and the directories within, this time. The new chmod permissions were like `0700`.

**SOLUTION:** What I did was, I set back the permissions for `/uploads` directory at `0755`, and selected the option in my FTP client to set the permission recursively to all sub-directories in the `/uploads` directory.

As in your case, I would also check the permissions on `/wp-content` directory.

[image: chmod]

Comment: thanks! i tried this though and 0755 still produces 404 for images.